# Add-ADGroupMember : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument

Tags: powershell

I am trying to add a ad user to the domain admin group but I keep getting the error A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Admins". Not sure how to fix this

Here is what I put into powershell

```
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity Domain Admins -Members bsaunders
```

Here is the full error

```
Add-ADGroupMember : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Admins'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-ADGroupMember -Identity Domain Admins -Members bsaunders
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Add-ADGroupMember], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.AddADGroupMember
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have an embedded space in the "Domain Admins" group name. that makes PoSh try to use  the "Domain" as the group name ... and then it tries to find something to use the "Admins" with. [*grin*]

wrap the group name in quotes and things otta work. i would use single quotes since PoSh tries to expand anything in double quotes.

hope that helps,
lee